# Is there a script that will automatically merge adjacent cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly competent with Google Sheets functions, but very new to the script element of things.

Please see the image. I want to automatically merge identical adjacent cells across the whole document. This sheet is auto-generating from another sheet (depending on the day of the week, etc) so this merging functionality can't be done manually and will change depending on the input.

The aim, as I'm sure you can guess, is to create an easy to read the schedule.

Is this easily solvable?

[image: Sheet Example]

Comment: Possible. But we can't write code for you. You have to do this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var s=0;
    var m=0;
    for(var j=1;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(vA[i][j] && vA[i][j]==vA[i][j-1]) {
        s=m+2;
        m++;
      }else{
        if(m) {
          var mr=sh.getRange(i+1,j-m,1,s).activate().mergeAcross(); 
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
        m=0;
        s=0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, this is a great thanks. The slightly problem now is that when you change the input (by changing a data validated drop down in cell A1), some of the cells might now be empty, but they remain merged, which creates an issue if you now need to only partially merge some of those cells with some others.

Also can this be automatically triggered so it updates when cell A1 is updated?

Comment: Edit: I think this script needs to first unmerge all cells before doing the above